# Step Wizard validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Im creating some validation inputs in my step wizard form, but is getting a error when i try to validate the input fields, it gives me a error of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: input_single[i].val is not a function
```

Here is my JS:

```
$(".next-step").click(function (e) {

        //Make some validation
        var curStep = $(this).closest(".tab-pane"),
            curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
            isValid = true;

        var input_single= curStep.find("input[type='text']");

        var temp = 0;

        //clean all
        $('.error-list').html("");

        if(input_single.length > 0){

            for(var i=0; i< input_single.length; i++){

                if (input_single[i].val() != ""){
                    temp = temp+1;
                }
            }

            if(temp === 0){
                isValid = false;
                $('.error-list').append("<li class='error'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i> Required field</li>");
            }
        }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing a DOM Element here `input_single[i].val() != ""` and you use the val() as is a DOM property, but actually is a Jquery function.

In your case you should try to use `input_single[i].value !== ""` instead.

Comment: I see i thought that when i called input_single is like being $('input')[0].val becasue in the above code i starting gathering the elments using "curStep = $(this)" using jquery operator, so i though automatlly the input was called like a jquery element.